# Docker Setup For Networking Application Development

Tags: docker

I need to develop one-to-one network communication applications between two or more applications. According to the network prototype, both nodes of the communication need to be on the same port. In a local (Linux) development environment, I can't map both applications to the same port. To solve the problem, I think of using Docker. I, however, don't know how to go about it. To get started, I try to build docker images of two applications. After building one of them, the second one can't be built due to the occupied port. I do some online search and don't see any helpful information. I use Spring Boot to build those applications and I know I need to use Kubernette for service discovery at some point later.

How shall I go about this?

Comment: You might look at [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) as a starting point.  If you have two containers, and they are on the same Docker-internal network, they can both have the same port but can use their container names as host names, only within the Docker setup.

Comment: Also consider making the port number configurable (both in client and server code) and just running both processes on the host with different ports as a development-only setup.